# Using Paypal (or alternative) so my customers can sell items directly

Tags: paypal

I've been searching Paypal's products and docs and I can't seen to confirm or deny if Paypal is a solution for what I need, so wanted to ask the community.

I run a web platform for creators to spin up websites. One common request is to create a page for them to sell their merch. I don't want to re-create Shopify/etc.. so have been telling them to go use that and link to their store from their website. But I'm wondering if there's an easy way to give them a very basic store experience using standard Paypal Buy Buttons.

My ideal approach:

1. Create a `ShopItems` model and users add items with price, description, shipping cost.
2. User adds their Paypal merchant ID
3. I generate a Buy with Paypal button that simply sends info to Paypal about the product being sold, how much to charge, etc..

I dont need any shopping cart functionality, and I dont want to have anything to do with the payment. I just want the end customer to feel like they're purchasing something (not sending someone $ via venmo), and have a place to add their shipping info, etc..

Currently, I see how a user can create accounts in their paypal account and then they're given a specific button for that item, but I'm trying to make this a little simpler where the user creates the product in my system and I just use Paypal for invoice/payment.

Would love any thoughts / ideas.

Comment: You can use a non-hosted PayPal button for this, and basically generate your own items and prices onto the web page, but it isn't recommended, on security grounds.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne how would i do this?

Comment: Don't do that. I mean you could, but that was the way to do it 5 years ago.

Comment: @PrestonPHX is right, but how to (not) do it is to have your customer go through the entire button creation process at PayPal exactly once and make sure *not* to enable the 'hosted button' option, and then send you the generated HTML. You can then vary the items any way you like as long as you preserve the item *names*, and they will show up that way. You will need a PayPal sandbox account to test it properly.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Exactly. Although I'd love to build a more feature-rich checkout experience at some point, I'm trying to keep things simple for me and the user at this point. Them having to do a full product setup on paypal, then have to copy a bunch of code and duplicate it on my site feels too heavy. So I like your original suggestion. If I generate my own items, how do I send it over to Paypal with shipping cost, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Integrate a version of PayPal Checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

Some sample demo code here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client (use the server version if you need robust payment completion notification -- this requires implementing two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ )

If you know the merchant ID you're processing transactions for, this can be specified when loading the SDK: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#merchant-id

Whether or not you specify a merchant ID on the SDK line, that same or some other identifier needs to be specified in the purchase_units `payee` object when setting up the transaction: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/